# CSOM give edit permissions to group on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm creating a new list in CSOM for SharePoint Online, but I'm very new to this so I'm stuck on changing the permissions.
There are 3 user groups, owners, visitors and members. I'd like to give the visitors editing rights on this list.

I've managed to break inheritance and get all the visitors with the following code, but I'm stuck on how to give them new permissions

```
newList.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
var visitors = ctx.Web.SiteGroups;
ctx.Load(visitors, groupitems => groupitems.Include(groupitem => groupitem.Title,
    groupitem => groupitem.LoginName).Where(groupitem=> groupitem.Title == visitorsGroupName));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to this one:

```
foreach(var grpUser in grpUsers)
{
    Principal user = ctx.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(grpUser);

    RoleDefinition writeDefinition = ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Edit");
    RoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefCollection = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);
    roleDefCollection.Add(writeDefinition);
    RoleAssignment newRoleAssignment = ctx.Web.RoleAssignments.Add(grpUser, roleDefCollection);
}

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

This assumes that there is an "Edit" permission level which is available by default in SharePoint. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I've followed you answer and got it to run without errors, but when I then check the user permissions in the list they still only have "read" permissions. Any idea what I might have done wrong?

Comment: You can find the code here: https://pastebin.com/5AgCRkn9 everything works fine except the permissions

Comment: Found the problem, had to change newList.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true); to newList.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);
Then your code worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
var EditRole= new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);
EditRole.Add(ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Editor));
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group visitors= ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("visitors");
ctx.Load(visitors);
newList.RoleAssignments.Add(visitors, EditRole);
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```